# STM32 Getting stable PWM Frequency and Duty Cycle

Tags: stm32, pwm

I have F401RB nucleo board Timer4 configured with these values
[image]

The PWM output varies considerably , frequency between 40kHz and 41.67 kHz and the duty Cycle between 50% and 52%.
[image]
Is there a way to achieve better stablity

With due respect to Sealese logic, is it the LA that lags in capturing real output ?

Answer (score 7):

You are attempting to read a 40 KHz signal at a 1 MHz sampling rate, in other words there are only 25 samples per cycle of your signal.  If there is a +/-1 error in reading a particular cycle (and there will *always* be a possibility of such an error, due to the complete lack of synchronization between the signal and the sampling), the displayed frequency will be off by a factor of 1/25 - either 38461 Hz or 41667 Hz.

If you wanted to determine the exact frequency to within 1% (for example), you'd need a sampling rate 100 times greater than the signal frequency.

Comment: exactly - set the speed 24MHz. Even the China made Sealae clones will do